# Anything wrong with this ground wire? Is it supposed to be insulated?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, grounding

Panel is from the late 1970's. Looks like there was some insulation on the ground wire, but most of it has come off. It's the same way through the crawlspace.

[image: Main ground wire]
[image: Main ground wire]

Comment: It is ok for a ground to be insulated but it should be green insulation. What would bother me would be if the ground is getting hot and causing the insulation damage.

Comment: Since you traced it into the crawlspace, can you see what it connects to? Copper water line or into the foundation? Usually ground wires like that are done by the phone company and are connected to the metal water line

Comment: EEK.. why are these ground wires connected to the neutral bus?

Comment: It connects to a copper water line

Answer (score -2):

The best solution is to attach the ground wire to a copper stake that is driven into the ground close to the home. Ground wires should be insulated as at some time they may be live and dangerous.

Comment: There is no requirement for insulating a ground wire. *If* a ground wire becomes energized, the OCPD or GFCI should break the circuit.